# Javafx 8 tableview add row and focus

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I would like to add a functionality of dirty/validated row to the tableview control, where the user will be forced to edit the newly added row, otherwise it will be removed.
What is best way to focus the first cell (the editor of which is `ComboboxTableCell`) of the newly added row. The new row is added with 
`tableview.getItems().getItems().addAll(new Item())`

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code of the controller and of the view :

```
public class SaleDetailController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TableView<SaleDetail> saleDetailTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<SaleDetail, Product> productColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<SaleDetail, Integer> quantityColumn;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    productColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(FXCollections.observableArrayList(DaoFactory.getProductDao().getAll())));
        productColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty(cellData.getValue().getProduct()));
        quantityColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
        quantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty(cellData.getValue().getQuantity()));
    }

   @FXML
   private void handleRemoveProductButton(ActionEvent event) {
       int selectedIndex = saleDetailTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
            saleDetailTable.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleAddProductButton(ActionEvent event) {
        SaleDetail saleDetail = new SaleDetail();
        saleDetail.setQuantity(0);
        Product product = new Product();
        saleDetail.setProduct(product);
        saleDetailTable.getItems().addAll(saleDetail);

        saleDetailTable.getSelectionModel().selectLast();
        saleDetailTable.requestFocus();
        saleDetailTable.getFocusModel().focus(saleDetailTable.getItems().size() - 1);
        saleDetailTable.edit(saleDetailTable.getFocusModel().getFocusedIndex(), productColumn);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox fx:id="saleDetailView" minWidth="500.0" spacing="15.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: #D3D3D3;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.zpavel.controller.SaleDetailController">
    <children>
        <HBox spacing="10.0">
            <children>
                <Label text="Products*" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAddProductButton" text="Add" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleRemoveProductButton" text="Remove" />
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <TableView fx:id="saleDetailTable" editable="true">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="productColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Product*" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="quantityColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Quantity*" />
            </columns>
            <columnResizePolicy>
                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
            </columnResizePolicy>
        </TableView>
    </children>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
    </padding>
</VBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `TableView.edit()` method:

```
tableview.getItems().getItems().add(new Item());
int lastItemIndex = tableview.getItems().size() - 1 ;

tableview.edit(lastItemIndex,  someColumn);
```

where `someColumn` is the `TableColumn` containing the cell you want to edit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply James. I have tried your solution. The problem is that the combobox in the cell does not switch to edit mode. I have also tried to use focusModel without success.

Comment: You probably need to create a [MCVE] reproducing the problem. Edit your question to include it.